# astype not cast float to int

Tags: pandas, dtype

I need to convert the dtype of the following column in `df1` from float to int

```
Index      ID
0        42.0
1       990.0
2       107.0
...
```

`Name: ID, Length: 478, dtype: float64`

Running `df2 = df1['ID'].astype('int',errors='ignore')` and then checking `dtype` of `df2` gives me back the exact same `dtype` (i.e. `float64`) for `df2`. Any idea what I'm missing here? Maybe it's super obvious - but I'd appreciate any pointers. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter `errors='ignore'` working differently like you think - if some error return same values, no conversation in [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

> errors{ 'raise', 'ignore'}, default 'raise'
> Control raising of exceptions on invalid data for provided dtype.

> raise : allow exceptions to be raised
> ignore : suppress exceptions. On error return original object.

Possible idea is first remove parameter:

```
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].astype('int')
```

If failed because missing values use [`integer na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), here `Int64`:

```
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].astype('Int64')
```

Comment: That was exactly it! Missing values where throwing an error which I ignored through the parameter leaving `NaN` for the missing values. Since `NaN` is a `float` ignoring it forced the `dtype` of the entire series to be a `float`. Using `IntergerArray` and the `"Int64"` (CAPITAL eye) solved this.